# Why is the delay between each .addstr() method call increasing/spiking?

Tags: python-3.x, curses

I'm creating a script using python curses and have created a slowprint function that calls `.addstr()` for each character in the provided string:

```
#utlis.py
from time import sleep

def slowprint(text, delay, stdscr, newline=True):
    for c in text:
        stdscr.addstr(c)
        stdscr.refresh()
        sleep(delay)
    #add a linebreak by default (i.e. unless otherwise specified via newline=False)
    if newline:
        stdscr.addstr("\n")
```

```
#main.py
import curses, utils
stdscr = curses.initscr()

def login():
    stdscr.clear()
    utils.slowprint("Please enter your username and password to continue", 0.05, stdscr)
    utils.slowprint("Select a user from the list below, using keys 0-9 or arrow keys to navigate", 0.05, stdscr)

def main(stdscr):
    stdscr.clear()
    utils.slowprint("--Press any key to wake up--", 0.05, stdscr)
    stdscr.getkey()
    login()
    
curses.wrapper(main) #init our app
```

Characters are suppose to output one at a time with a pause of `delay` seconds between them. Which works fine at 0.1+ seconds delay.

However, at lower delay times outputting ~20-30 characters will cause delay between each output to increase.

I've tried increasing and decreasing the delay to no effect, as well as substituting `time.sleep()` with `curses.napms()`.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please provide some driver code that runs this function with numbers that replicate your behavior.

Comment: @blackbrandt made the appropriate changes

Comment: Use  curses `napms` rather than `sleep` (the latter may suspend the process, making it do *nothing*, which interferes with writing text to the screen)

Comment: I’ve already tried `curses.napms`, the problem still persists @ThomasDickey